# How to authenticate MailChimp on DKIM in 1and1

Tags: mailchimp, cname, dkim

I've searched everywhere about this issue and found nothing. 
I want to authenticate my domain in MailChimp. My website is hosted in 1and1. 
These are the instructions from MailChimp: 
Create a CNAME record for `k1._domainkey.YOURDOMAIN.com` with this value:
**dkim.mcsv.net**

The problem is that 1and1 only allows CNAME records on subdomains, so I created a subdomain named `mail.MYDOMAIN.com` and set up a CNAME record for it with the alias `dkim.mcsv.net`. Waited for 24 hours and it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what's wrong and the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to setup a subdomain. 1and1 previously didn't allow CNAME records on the main domain, but they now do. 4 months ago, I ran into the same problem you did, but I've just now verified my domain on 1and1 with mailchimp using CNAME. Just follow mailchimp's directives as they are.

Answer (score 1):

1and1 do things deferently. Even though Mailchimp says - to create subdomain k1._domainkey.YOURDOMAIN.com or k1._domainkey.MYDOMAIN.com it does not work.

Also the interface accepts the values differently by separating them.

Here is what I have on "**my working set up**", to register your Domain authentication with **Mailchimp using 1and1**, please follow.

1. Log in and go to your Control Panel
2. Click Manage Domains
3. Click the three dots next to Actions, Select Advanced Settings.
4. Scroll down to DNS Settings, click edit.
5. For DKIM: Create a CNAME record for k1._domainkey.yourname.com with this value:
6. Scroll down to TXT, CNAME and SRV Records.
7. Click button Add record
8. Select CNAME from the drop down menu
9. In the Prefix box put "k1._domainkey" no quotes.
10. In the Value box put "dkim.mcsv.net" no quotes.
11. click Add.
12. To create a SPF: Create a TXT record for your domain.com
13. Click Add record for the last time.
14. Select TXT from the drop down menu.
15. In the Value box put "v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all" no quotes.
16. click Add.
17. Now click Save!

All done... Wait 28/48 hours and go back to MailChimp and verify

Comment: Looks like 1and1 interface has changed since this was posted.

Comment: Let me know when you are able to get an answer from 1and1.

Answer (score 0):

the only correct way is to do exactly as MailChimp says - to create subdomain k1._domainkey.YOURDOMAIN.com or k1._domainkey.MYDOMAIN.com (not mail.MYDOMAIN.com) and set it value to dkim.mcsv.net.
When receiving part gets email it will found then that it refers in DKIM signature to lookup key in senders k1._domainkey subdomain.

Comment: The problem is that 1and1 doesn't allow "k1._domainkey" as a subdomain name, it says "invalid character".

Comment: hm, though it's not quite relevant answer or solution but if I would be in such situation I would consider transfer my dns to some other service for example to cloudflare dns manament, that i personally use on one project